# How to disable myfaces caching resource URLs?

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I've found that MyFaces is only calling `ViewHandler.getResourceURL(FacesContext, String)` once per resource, so it seems to be caching the resulting values, and reuse it during the entire lifespan of the application.

This can be interesting (and works), but it ruins my strategy with a custom `ViewHandlerWrapper` that makes the urls relative to the current request. This works nicely with Mojarra, but clearly, with MyFaces, it works only on the first call (eg. /login.xhtml)... when I then navigate to /data/list.xhtml , the relative urls to JS and CSS files are wrong (but still the same as they were on the login page).

Is there any way to disable this behaviour? Or work around it in some way?

Comment: Did you try if setting the application in development mode makes it work? (not that it is a solution, just curious) And I'm curious to why you want this new behaviour? I would expect it to result in a performance degradation. But iirc, you can plug in custom implementations of almost everything in JSF, but I have no links at hand